# Menu hover effect when scrolling on the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hover

I created a site with a top navigation bar that has hyperlinks to anchors in the same page for different content.

I'm trying to create a hover effect on the navigation bar when a user scrolls past the corresponding anchor in the same page. For example, when I scroll past link1's anchor, I want the top navigation hyperlink for link1 to change to a different color.

I tried searching Google but can't find anything relevant to do this.

Can someone point me in the right direction or provide some code examples for how I might do this using HTML/CSS/Jquery/Javascript, etc?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want a [ScrollSpy plugin](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#scrollspy).